# Javadoc : is it possible to avoid fully qualified names in package-info using {@link}

Tags: javadoc

When adding documentation to `package-info.java` I can't figure out a way to avoid using fully qualified names in `{@link}` comments. Having fully qualified names makes documentation much less readable in unformatted comments and formatted output. `import` doesn't work because we are in `package-info.java` has anyone else run into this issue and found a solution or do we just have to use fully qualifed names in `package-info.java` while using `{@link}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the link, add the text you want displayed. For instance:

```
{@link com.company.whatever Whatever}
```

should show up as [Whatever](http://example.com/).

This is documented in the [Javadoc Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link).